# Saving recursive function results to a global data frame in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate the functionality of the memoise package in base R by saving the outputs of a recursive function in a data frame. I have this function "P" and then I made this "metaP" wrapper that will run P(n) if metaP(n) hasn't been run before and then save the results of P(n), or it produces the previously saved output.  My issue is it only works at the first level.  If I run metaP(5) it will save the output of metaP(5), but in order to get P(5) it also had to calculate P(4) and the results of P(4) aren't getting saved. I'm assuming it's getting lost in the recursive environments, but when I tried using the assign function and setting it to the global environment it still didn't work.

In the example below, I run metaP 5 through 10, and df has 5 through 10 saved, but it doesn't have 1 through 5 saved, some of which must have been calculated to come up with the answers of 5 through 10.

```
df <- data.frame(n = 0, pn = 1)  

metaP <- function(n) {
  if (!n %in% df$n) df <<- rbind(df, data.frame(n = n, pn = P(n)))
  df[df$n == n, "pn"]
}

P <- function(n) {
  if (n < 0) return(0)
  k <- rep(1:((sqrt(24 * n + 1) + 1) / 6), each = 2) * c(1, -1)
  return(sum((-1) ^ (k + 1) * sapply(n - k * (3 * k - 1) / 2, metaP)) %% 1e6)
}

sapply(5:10, metaP)
df
```

Comment: Save all dataframes to a list, then do: `do.call("rbind", mylist)` to get a combined dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is kind of subtle.  The expression

```
df <<- rbind(df, data.frame(n = n, pn = P(n)))
```

is ambiguous, because the `?rbind` documentation doesn't define the order in which the two arguments to `rbind()` are evaluated.  It appears that R is evaluating `df`, then doing the recursive call, then appending that result to the saved value of `df`.  Any changes to the global variable that happened during the recursive call are lost.

To fix this, rewrite the conditional part as

```
if (!n %in% df$n) {
  newval <- data.frame(n = n, pn = P(n))
  df <<- rbind(df, newval)
}
```

(I'd also suggest adding parens to the test, and writing it as `if (!(n %in% df$n))`, because it's not immediately obvious that these are the same.  I was confused about this in an earlier answer to this question.  But checking `?Syntax` shows that `%in%` has higher priority than `!`.)

Comment: That makes sense!  As far as the typo, I remember reading in R Inferno that `!n %in% df$n` and `!(n %in% df$n)` evaluate the same way, even though the first one looks like it shouldn't. I played around with them again and it sure looks like they always evaluate the same way.